# Does Euler's rotation theorem assume a continuous movement over time?

Tags: geometry, isometry, kinematics

Or can we apply **ANY** isometry in a sphere and it will have a fixed diameter? Regardless if it is discontinuous in time. Would absolutely any discontinuous isometry be a rotation in a sphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kind of.

It assumes the isometry is "orientation-preserving", thus, it ignores reflection around symmetry axes plus some other weird isometries that would not happen in real world [What are some isometries of $S^2$ without fixed points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321990/what-are-some-isometries-of-s2-without-fixed-points)